# how to adjust body height in layout component

Tags: html, css, blazor, maui

I am making an app with maui, hosting blazor.

I have made a layout, both the AppBarTop and the appBarBottom `position: fixed;`
the problem is that my body now takes up the entire screen, overlaying my app bars (they are underneath them, but when inspecting, you can see they take up their space too).
I tried setting the position of the bars to sticky, but then they scroll, since they are hosted in the container then.

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<AppBarTop />
<Navigation />
@Body
<AppBarBottom/>
```

for reference, my top bar looks like this :

```
<header class="top-app-bar">
<div class="container">
    <div class="left-section">
        <div class="circle-placeholder"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-section">
        <h1 class="text">@FullName</h1>
        <p class="text">Welcome!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.top-app-bar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
    align-items: center;
    height: 120px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #323232;
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
    flex: 1;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

I am missing to see how my body can adjust its size to take in account of the header and the footer.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with blazor, and even less with maui, but I can do basic positioning.

1. The whole point of `fixed` is to take it out of the doc flow.
2. The type of positioning you need is indeed `sticky`.
3. Sticky needs `top: 0;` to work. Add it and it will stop to scroll.